# authenticate With Password failed in XMPP?

Tags: ios, xmpp

Connect to my company server is ok with the sample iPhoneXMPP app from [github.com/robbiehanson](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework), and then to authentication failed:

```
- (void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender{
    NSLog(@"connected --->YES");
    isOpen = YES;
    NSError *error = nil;
    [xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:@"password" error:&error];
}
```

return error:
Domain=XMPPStreamErrorDomain Code=4 "No suitable authentication method found" UserInfo=0x9b61440 {NSLocalizedDescription=No suitable authentication method found}

And the `username` can be nikename or phoneNumber, can not be complete like name@example.com

Comment: hey, did u hot solution, i have same issue

Comment: i use **openfire** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved issue by deleting `sasl.mechs` from System Properties in openfire.

For more details, you can refer my question on github at following link: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/issues/576